# unable to connect to tcp port running in docker

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, akka

I have written a mqqt broker using sbt and Akka. I run fine on my local machine but I am unable to connect to the broker when I run my code in the docker container.I see broker is running fine on port 1883. 
Docker logs:-

```
[DEBUG] [02/17/2018 04:24:29.682] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://TcpServer)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [02/17/2018 04:24:29.853] [TcpServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://TcpServer/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Successfully bound to /127.0.0.1:1883
[INFO] [02/17/2018 04:24:29.860] [TcpServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://TcpServer/user/tcp] listening on port 1883
```

My dockerfile:-

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.16
RUN curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb &&  apt-get update && apt-get install sbt && sbt sbtVersion

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
EXPOSE 1883
CMD sbt run
```

Docker run command

```
docker run -v "$HOME/.ivy2":/root/.ivy2 -p 1883:1883 messanger:v1
```

docker container ls

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
6a0a6aee317f        messanger:v1        "/bin/sh -c 'sbt run'"   6 hours ago         Up 6 hours          0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp   epic_goldberg
```

I can connect to broker by login to docker machine but not from my local machine. Running mqtt client logs in docker

```
root@e14df5e36def:/# python mqtt_subscriber.py
Connected with result code 0
<paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x7fe5a66cb510> None 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs, you can see your app binding to the loopback interface:

```
[DEBUG] [02/17/2018 04:24:29.682] [run-main-0] [EventStream(akka://TcpServer)] Default Loggers started [DEBUG] [02/17/2018 04:24:29.853] 
[TcpServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://TcpServer/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Successfully bound to /127.0.0.1:1883 [INFO] [02/17/2018 04:24:29.860] 
[TcpServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://TcpServer/user/tcp] listening on port 1883
```

Your app needs to bind to interface `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`. Containers have their own namespaced loopback interface that docker port forwarding can't access.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to docker. Can you be a bit more specific? I tried running -p 0.0.0.0:1883:1883 still unable to connect

Comment: @abhishek_rathaur Your application, not the docker command. From the logs of your app, it shows that it's binding to the loopback interface. You'll need to change your code or pass a configuration to your application.

Comment: thanks a lot  @bmitch. I changes ip of my broker from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0. It is working fine now. I guess I need to read more theory about docker